# java-Not getting the result with decimal places

Tags: java, floating-point

I am doing simple calculation in java. Expected result is 51.3348 but what I am getting is 51.0, here is my calculation

```
    float percent = (7819140000l-3805200000l)*100/7819140000l;
```

Is that problem with datatype? How can I resolve this to get value as 51.3348

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It is being truncated because you are not using any floats in the equation.

Comment: even casting to float will work

Comment: try this onepublic String format_Decimal(double decimalNumber) {
  NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
  nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(5);
  nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
  nf.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
  String x = nf.format(decimalNumber);
  return x;
 }double percent=(7819140000l-3805200000l)*100f/7819140000l;

Comment: long Division Yields long result. to get float result either specify value as float by appending 'f'                                                                                      float percent = (7819140000l-3805200000l)*100f/7819140000l;                                                                   or Explicitly cast it.                                                                                            float percent = (float)(7819140000l-3805200000l)*100f/7819140000l;

Answer (score 1):

add an f to one of the values:

```
float percent = (7819140000l-3805200000l)*100f/7819140000l;
```

if yiu do not do it, Java will make a devision by long values

Comment: I would use a double instead of float, even though the OP only needs 6 digits of accuracy. This preserves half a tirllion times more precision